# Preg_replace BBCode Link

Tags: php, preg-replace, bbcode

I have this bbcode:

```
[url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1bIEK1h150]If I offer you my soul[/url]
```

for example. How can I turn this into this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1bIEK1h150" target="_blank">If I offer you my soul</a>
```

Comment: +1 for the video and lyric you chose in your question.

Comment: I think we need a Tony-the-pony answer for all BBcode questions too. The [center] can not hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a regular expression. Taking into account that bbcode can have a text URL or only the URL, you will need two statements:

```
$message = preg_replace('@\[url=([^]]*)\]([^[]*)\[/url\]@', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('@\[url\]([^[]*)\[/url\]@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $message);
```

Also, if you're parsing bbcode from PHPBB, it can have a unique user identifier:

```
$uid = '[0-9a-z]{5,}';
$message = preg_replace('@\[url=([^]]*):'. $uid . '\]([^[]*)\[/url:'. $uid . '\]@', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('@\[url:'.         $uid . '\]([^[]*)\[/url:'. $uid . '\]@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $message);
```