# Replacing eregi_replace with preg_replace

Tags: php, html

So I've looked everywhere for how to do this, and I've found a few threads, but none have helped me... I understand /how/ to replace it in general, but this example is odd (not my code, I took over from someone else), so I'm not sure how to replace it without it giving me errors everywhere.

One of the examples is this:

```
$content = eregi_replace("\\[url=([^\\[]*)\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/url\\]","<a href=\"\\1\" target=_blank>\\2</a>",$content);
```

This is within a function, which converts $content to a BB_Code.
I've tried the following:

```
$content = preg_replace('/[url=([^\\[]*)\\]([^\\[]*)\\[/url\\]/i','<a href=\"\\1\" target=_blank>\\2</a>',$content);
```

But it throws me an "unknown modifier" in 'r' error.
Also tried

```
    $content = preg_replace('/[url=([^[]*)]([^[]*)[/url]/i','<a href=\"\\1\" target=_blank>\\2</a>',$content);
```

But again, unknown modifier in 'r'.

I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I'm just trying to understand fully how to replace this so I can fix the syntax...

Thanks for any help though!

Comment: Have you looked this up? It has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Approaching this from a different angle, [this post may provide you an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726369/preg-replace-bbcode-link)

Comment: @RiggsFolly that worked! Thank you so much! I should've really looked up BBcode with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been trying to remove the wrong kind of slashes. You need to remove forward slashes (`/`) instead of backslashes (`\`) since `/` marks the end of a regular expression.

Just escape the `/` before url:

```
\\[url=([^\\[]*)\\]([^\\[]*)\\[\\/url\\]
```